# Probability confusion regarding different size of probability space

Tags: probability

Say that if A and B is playing a game using a fair coin, A represents head and B represents tail, the first guy that win 3 of his symbol wins. In the middle of the game the result is A, B, A the question ask what is the chance that A will win?

so the sample space is below

1.A

2.B,B

3.B,A

so naively A has 2 out of 3 chance of winning

Now suppose that A and B is playing the same game, except now the rule is that there are 5 flips the guy that got 3 of his symbol wins

and below is the sample space

1.A, B

2.A, A

3.B, B

4.B, A

so now naively A has 3 out 4 chance of winning.

but this means the termination of winning condition decrease the chance of A winning?

Comment: Yeah, didnt realize that < block the word, now I added the result of the middle game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample space with not all outcomes equally likely is fine, as long as we take into account the relevant probabilities. However, it we can arrange to make all outcomes equally likely, the analyis is likely to be easier, with a diminished probability of error.

In the first sample space, the three outcomes described are **not** all equally likely. The probability of $A$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, while the probability of each of $BB$ and $BA$ is $\frac{1}{4}$. The outcomes $A$ and $BA$ have player A winning, so her probability of winning is $\frac{3}{4}$.

In the second analysis, the outcomes listed are all equally likely, so the fact that the probability is $\frac{3}{4}$ is very clear.

Comment: You are welcome. In a sense, the question is very similar to one about $2$ child families, under the usual assumptions. One could decide there are three possible outcomes, $2$ girls, $2$ boys, or $1$ of each. That's fine, except that the three outcomes are not equally likely. In particular, the probability of $1$ of each turns out to be $1/2$, not $1/3$.